# Can I use only cellular network (3G or EDGE), even if WIFI is connected on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, connection, cellular-network

I was wondering whether I can use the cellular network (3G or 2G or whatever they may have) even if the WIFI is connected and working.
I noticed that Apple has a "Reachability" sample code, but that would only tell me if I can connect using a cellular network; instead, I would like to actually use ONLY the cellular network.

Best Regards,
Noam.

Comment: Why would you care which connection the user is using? Why would you want to limit the user the slowest pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I wouldn't imagine so.

My understanding is that if the device is connected to Wifi, 3G is not used for data and all data traffic travels via Wifi.

Only cellular data to another cellular device would use the phone provider's network.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely YES. You should combine Reachability notifications with network interfaces enumeration. And - this point is much important: use BSD socket's bind() call to bind to CONCRETE IP address. Don't use 0.0.0.0 and your app will be network-adaptive and awaring. My poor gist example: https://gist.github.com/avesus/fdb465b60a4f5204845c

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to accomplish this would be to detect if the user is on WiFi (example code is in the "Reachability" example you cited), and if so, prompt them to disable WiFi prior to using your app.